# 7x5 grid with square elements visible without scrolling

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a grid where all elements have the same width and height. I'm currently using a GridView, but it seems that I'll have the same results with TableLayout and nested LinearLayouts.

The problem is that I can't use a fixed size for the grid, as each user can be using a device of different size.

So, how can I create a grid with 7 lines and 5 columns, where all elements have the same width and height (squares), and they are all visible without having to scroll the view?

Comment: Anybody else has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size of the grid "cell" to 20% width in regards to the ull screen, so that 5 cells can fit on it, and about 14% height, which is approx. 100/7. Also, try to change the width of the grid layout to 100% in the layout.xml file if you have not done so.

Comment: This won't work. Suppose that screen is 600x1024, than diving the width by 5 and the height by 7 would create a cell with 120x146 pixels.

Comment: That being said, it wouldn't work if you hard-coded it for this screen size either. Try rounding the width to the nearest multiple of 5: `double number = Math.round((width + 2.5)/ 5.0) * 5.0;` Then divide the result by 5 (since the width is always less than the height) and set that as your cell width and height. Then just center the table.